# Mediawiki - Using PHP inside a form or page

Tags: php, templates, textbox, mediawiki

I need to use some PHP code inside of a MediaWiki form.  Basically, I need to use some PHP date stuff and create a few infoboxes based on timeframes.  Is there a way to use PHP to generate a "template" in the "edit" box?

I'm very new to developing with MediaWiki, so I'm not sure how MediaWiki exactly works, and this is a very small project, so I haven't really dived into any documentation for the most part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this myself with a MediaWiki plugin called SemanticForms:
[SemanticForms](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension%3aSemantic_Forms)

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly add [secure HTML](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:RawMsg) within a wiki page. It seems there is also a **[securePHP extension](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:SecurePHP)**. I haven't tried the PHP one myself but the HTML one works very well.